# List elements are leaving a space where the style is

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` with `li`s that have a style of `list-style:none`. In other words, I wanted the bullets removed.

Although it removes the styling (the default bullets), it leaves an empty space in that spot rather than removing the empty space along with the style. Is there a way to remove the space of a `li`'s elements style? (This makes the margins on the left look off in the call out box I'm placing it in.)

Thanks!

Comment: yup. that's certainly possible.

Comment: Go and learn the box model https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/ and how to inspect elements on the website.

Comment: Oops I didn't realize the space created next to the li element was padding of the li element. For some reason I thought it was something being prepended to the li element.